# where do domain names come from?

Tags: hosting, dns

Hi I want to develop my own hosting site but i do not know how should i get hosting names  ??
How these hosting companies get these domain names ????

Comment: "Where do domain names come from?" I'll tell you when you're older.

Comment: ha ha ha what are you doing on this site?...   anyways, when you do hosting, you aren't required to sell domain names.  Customers get their own names, you just host the data and possibly provide DNS.  But if you are asking these types of questions, you should NOT get involved in the hosting business.  It's completely saturated anyways and you will not make a penny.

Comment: When a website meets a web developer, they have a special hug and a domain name comes out

Comment: I think this should have been moved to serverfault - it's a valid and on-topic question, if very basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Domain names must be purchased from a [domain name registrar](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Domain_registrar).  Hosting companies are often resellers for registrars.

Many hosting companies and registrars offer easy-to-use reseller or affiliate programs - they will typically include lots of information on their website.  This is by far the best way to get into selling hosting and domain names, as they will take care of the technical side of things.  If you have a unique way of selling hosting, this can be quite profitable, but beware of trying to sell online, as this market is *extremely* crowded and competative already.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the [ICANN Accreditation Overview](http://www.icann.org/registrars/accreditation.htm).

Some notes I got from another website (disclaimer: may be out of date)

1. You need a $500,000 liability policy
   (around $5k USD per annum)
2. $70,000 liquid funds
3. $2,500 application fee
4. $4,000 annual accreditation fee

An alternative and cheaper route is finding a reseller, but you will have to pass some serious volume to make any meaningful amount of money.

Find a better niche.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you're asking, but if you mean to say that you want to start a business hosting other folks's web sites, then you let your customers worry about getting their own domain names.  It is nevertheless possible for you to become a domain-name registrar and add that to your business model.

Although I have to say that this is not a typical Stackoverflow question (supposed to be programming questions here).  I think this question fits better on ServerFault, and would probably get better answers.  You should make the question clearer, though.